# UserDeletingRow DataGridView causing program to terminate

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataViewGrid that is tied to a datasource.  When the UserDeletingRow event is executed it allows a row to be deleted from grid and database.

But when executed it abends the program in the frmMain with System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred.

I have tried to place try and catch code around the delete processing but the code executes completely before the frmMain termination.

I have even added try catch logic around the Application.Run(new frmMain()); and I still cannot catch the error.

Surely there is a way to use UserDeletingRow with a delete stored proc and reload the updated datatable into the grid, right?

Any help is most welcome.  I will attach code upon request.

Comment: You should at least post the `UserDeletingRow` event.

Comment: Depending on the datasource, the DB Provider objects can do all that for you so you dont have to "update the datatable"

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out just a few minutes ago.  1 1/2 days shot but I found that I was referencing the datatable after deleting the record and that was causing the -1 indexing problem.  I thing the strangest thing was how I could not catch the error because it was being thrown in the Application.Run in the Main form.